# How can we show that each component of a 2-regular graph is a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

I have done quite a few examples and this statement turns out to be true in each case. However I'm not sure how to formally prove it. Does there exist a theorem that can help with such type of proof?

Comment: What about a graph with two vertices and one edge? That seems to be a bipartite graph, and it has no even cycles as far as I can see. Did you leave out some assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that a connected 2-regular graph is a cycle. Take a vertex $x$ of the graph, and consider the longest simple path $p$ (meaning no edge appears twice in $p$)starting with $x$. Let $y$ be the last vertex of $p$. Two cases a) $y=x$ and b) $y\ne x$. In the first case $p$ is a cycle, and no vertex in the graph outside $p$ is connected to a vertex in $p$, so the graph is disconnected (a contradiction) or is equal to $p$. b) There is a vertex $z$ in the graph which is connected to $y$ by an edge which is not in $p$ (because $y$ has degree $2$). Since $p$ was a maximal simple path either $z=x$ or $z$ is equal to another vertex of $p$. The second option is impossible because $p$ was the largest simple path starting at $x$. If $x=z$ then we get a cycle and the rest is as in case a).

Comment: How come we can assume that its a connected graph?

Comment: Every connected component is a connected graph. You need to consider one component at a time.

Comment: Do you have any other objections? I'd like to move on.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is, "do all bipartite graphs have even cycles." The answer is "no, lots of bipartite graphs are acyclic; in fact, *all* acyclic graphs are bipartite." You seem to be answering some question about $2$-regular graphs.

Comment: Look at the question  before edit. That is the one I answered.